# Fast map implementation in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a working implementation now that maps keys of ranges, like so:

```
class Range {
public:
    Range(int from, int to = -1) : _from(from), _to( to >= 0 ? to : from) {}
    bool operator < (const Range& item) {
        return _to < item._from;
    }
    bool operator == (const Range& item) {
        return item._from >= _from && item._to <= _to;
    }
private:
    int _from, _to;
};

typedef std::map<Range, MappedType> my_map_type;
```

Cool thing with this is that I can do:

```
my_map_type m;
m[Range(0, 20)] = Item1;
m[Range(30,40)] = Item2;

my_map_type::iterator it = m.find(15);
assert(it->second == Item1);
it = m.find(40);
assert(it->second == Item2);
it = m_find(25);
assert(it == m.end());
```

But I need a faster map implementation than **std::map**. Insertions are OK to be slow, but finds must be really quick. Tried **boost::unordered_map** but I cannot get it to work with **Range** class (although I've implemented **boost::hash_value** for Range objects). A **find** returns nothing (and **operator==** isn't even called during a **find**, which I find odd)

Ideas ?

Comment: Maybe your hash is buggy? `operator==` is only called once an item with the correct hash has been found.

Comment: Hmm.. I think I know why. Since unordered_map uses a hash value, the hash value of the search key (used with find) will only match entries with singular Range (i.e. from == to)

Comment: Your hash value implementation would be useful. Also, have you tried using a sorted vector with binary search instead of a map? These usually have faster search (but slower inserts).

Comment: hash_value is simply boost::hash_value( *((long long*)&_from) ). Thanks for the vector tip, sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Maybe boost token map? http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/tokenmap/libs/tokenmap/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @nice: handy container, but... it's not really associative.

Comment: No, but for mapping ranges of bytecodes when parsing binary protocols, it's great :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with an hash table, your definition of `operator==` can't be compatible with an hash function: In your code `Range(10, 20) == Range(15, -1)` but there is no way an hash function can return the same hash.

In general, hash and equality must be compatible: `x == y` must imply `hash(x) == hash(y)`. Of course the converse is not true.

So you need some comparison-based structure, like the tree-based `map`. Instead of using a broken `operator==` which could give you problems, you can define a correct equality comparator and use `map::lower_bound` that does exactly what you are trying to do.

If it is too slow for you, you can use a sorted vector and use `std::lower_bound`. Search time is O(log n) which is asymptotically the same as `std::map` but much faster in practice (no pointer chasing, better locality). However it has linear update (insertion/deletion) time.

Otherwise you may want to have a look at specialized structures, like [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), but they are not implemented in the STL (maybe Boost?).

Anyway, the implicit `Range(int)` constructor is misleading and potentially harmful. You should declare it as `explicit` and use, for example, `find(Range(40))` in place of `find(40)`.

Comment: Just clarifying: Linear *update time* -- not linear *search time*. +1

Comment: @Giuseppe: interval trees are not meant for non-overlapping ranges.

Comment: @Matthieu: where did the OP say that his intervals are non-overlapping? Anyway, interval trees support point-in-interval queries (which is what I assume the OP is trying to do), whether the ranges are overlapping or not is irrelevant. Do you mean that they are overkill?

Comment: @Giuseppe: Yes that's what I mean, they are extremely sophisticated beasts for a very simple need. And sophistication and performance usually don't go hand in hand, so it won't solve the OP issue.

Comment: @Matthieu: you are right but I can't see anything in the question that implies that the ranges are disjoint. How do you know? BTW, if they are disjoint, a simple `map` on the first endpoint and a `lower_bound` would do.

Comment: @Giuseppe: I assume it is, given the implementation of `==` which tests for inclusion. But anyway the `Range` class is completely screwed up, since `==` is not even symmetric...

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do will not work, whether with `std::map` or any other container. Your `operator <` and `operator ==` do not match the traditional requirements for these operators:

- If `a == b` and `a == c`, then `b == c` : in your situation, `[1,2] == [0,100]` and `[98,99] == [0,100]` but obviously `[1,2] != [98,99]`.
- If `a < b` is true then `b < a` is false : in your situation, `[2,4] < [1,3]` is true but `[1,3] < [2,4]` is also true.

So, your `std::map` implementation will also fail in some situations.

Not only that, but `std::map` will only return one range while it could be expected that a given item could be within several ranges in the map.

If you can safely assume that none of the ranges overlap, then sort the ranges based on their `from` value alone, use `upper_bound` to extract the range with the larges `from` smaller than the value you are looking for, and compare with that range's `to` to determine if it's an actual match.

Comment: The ranges I use are non-overlapping so a m.find(N) works all the time (I've tested it extensively)

Comment: Ok, I did a typed range (which can hold what I want to "map"), and use lower_bound with Pred on _to, then check that value is >= _from. That way I can find the correct range. Hopefully faster then... :)

Comment: Hmm... the vector implementation was actually slower than the map implementation. How disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using std::map<> which is normally implemented as a red-black tree. boost::multi_index container also offers red-black tree based container but with compressed nodes (smaller by the size of a pointer), so it is going to be faster than std::map<> due to smaller working set.

Another option is to use a hash, so that some of you lookups when there are no hash collisions will be O(1).

Comment: Yes, but consider me doing m.find(30), then I want to return the entry with Range(10, 35) as key, but Range(30, 30) will not have the same hash as Range(10, 35)...